# Python multiprocessing exception handling

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Given the following program structure I am looking for a way to:

- Detect child failures in the parent process
- Terminate all processes (parent and children) and exit with status code 1
- Achieve the above without relaxing the max queue size

Here's the code:

```
import multiprocessing


def worker1(queue1, queue2):
    while True:
        item = queue1.get()
        if item == 10:
            raise
        if item == 'stop':
            return
        # do something with item that generates multiple queue entries
        for x in xrange(1000):
            queue2.put(x)


def worker2(queue2, queue3):
    while True:
        item = queue2.get()
        if item == 'stop':
            return
        # do something with item, only one result to pass to the next queue
        queue3.put(1)


def worker3(queue3):
    while True:
        item = queue3.get()
        if item == 'stop':
            return
        # do something with item


def main():
    queue1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue2 = multiprocessing.Queue(100)
    queue3 = multiprocessing.Queue(100)

    pool1 = multiprocessing.Pool(2, worker1, (queue1,queue2,))
    pool2 = multiprocessing.Pool(8, worker2, (queue2,queue3,))
    pool3 = multiprocessing.Pool(4, worker3, (queue3,))

    for i in xrange(100):
        queue1.put(i)
    for _ in range(pool1.__dict__['_processes']):
        queue1.put('stop')
    pool1.close()
    pool1.join()

    for _ in range(pool2.__dict__['_processes']):
        queue2.put('stop')
    pool2.close()
    pool2.join()

    for _ in range(pool3.__dict__['_processes']):
        queue3.put('stop')
    pool3.close()
    pool3.join()

    print 'finished'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do the code works? If yes, go to CodeReview. If not, explain the problem to us.

Comment: The code works, but the parent process is unaware of uncaught exceptions in the subprocesses. I am looking for some help to detect them and shutdown all processes (parent and children) once an uncaught exception is raised.

Comment: Well, the usual way to catch exceptions is to use `try: ... except: raise ~exception type here~`

Comment: sure, but those don't propagate to the parent process - which is where my problem lies

Comment: Wouldn't kill the process and restart it after a exception solve your problem? I mean, write a daemon to watch for process kill messages. So you will restart  the process,and the parent will be notified.

Comment: I haven't come across this technique, if you could elaborate with an example or a link pointing to such a technique it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't implemented it in python yet, but the idea is to run a process that monitor the other processes, waiting for some message.When that happens, you get notified. Maybe threads would be easier to do this, for the simpler interthread communication.

Comment: You don't use n `Processes`. Reread the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

Answer (score 1):

You are kind of misusing the `Pool` objects here.

Instead of `Pool` objects, use `Process` objects directly.

Program the worker functions to exit with an error code when an exception is raised.

Then you can use the `is_alive()` method to check if the process is still running, and check the `exitcode` property of dead processes.